Is Cesium.js able to handle 3DTileset in CRS different from EPSG:4978
If I have a tileset generated in EPSG:7664 is it possible to load it in Cesium and how to tell it that coordinate system reference is different from the default EPSG:4978?
I found it the 3D tiles specification that there is semantic called TILESET_CRS_GEOCENTRIC which is

The geocentric coordinate reference system (CRS) of the tileset. Values include, but are not limited to:

"EPSG:4978" — WGS 84
"EPSG:7656" — WGS 84 (G730)
"EPSG:7658" — WGS 84 (G873)
"EPSG:7660" — WGS 84 (G1150)
"EPSG:7662" — WGS 84 (G1674)
"EPSG:7664" — WGS 84 (G1762)
"EPSG:9753" — WGS 84 (G2139)
"EPSG:7842" — GDA2020
"UNKNOWN" — CRS is unknown


Is it something that should be defined in the tileset.json file?
I've also found some discussions on GitHub about adding extension for CRS definition, but it seems not to be implemented yet.

I think it is not possible.
